# Cocos2d-x 2.0 - How do I Take Advantage of Sprite Auto-Batching Work?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have seen references to a new 'auto batching' feature in Cocos2d-x 3.0, and even saw somewhere that they no longer recommending using SpriteBatchNodes. So how do I batch draw calls without using BatchNodes?

I can't find anything in the documentation but the vaguest references to this feature. 
- https://docs.google.com/document/d/17zjC55vbP_PYTftTZEuvqXuMb9PbYNxRFu0EGTULPK8/edit#heading=h.3ssqg87hovgw

I tried simply getting rid of my SpriteBatchNode and creating my Sprites using files but the number of draw calls went up by about 1 per sprite :)

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question ?

Comment: No. I looked into it some more and it seems to be a pretty simple feature. If you keep drawing the same image over and over it will batch it automatically. Have not verified.

Comment: On the cocos2d-x site they recommended not using SpriteBatchNode. So I guess there must be some way to get the benefit of autobatching. I found some cocos china posts (translated with google translate) that say that the sprites have to be of the same texture id ,material,glprogram, blending function, and that quad commands must be consecutive. Also it applies only for sprites and particles. Do you know what materials they are talking about ? And does that help solve the problem? If you figure it out post your answer here.

Comment: see http://www.cnblogs.com/adoontheway/p/3804090.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved this, and it's pretty simple. I just changed all of my SpriteBatchNodes to Nodes and preloaded my atlases with

```
SpriteFrameCache* spriteFrameCache = SpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
spriteFrameCache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("spritesheets/xxx.plist");
```

The number of draw calls didn't change compared to what it was with SpriteBatchNode.

This new architecture is way more flexible than SpriteBatchNode. For example, the calls are properly batched if you do
   Node -> Node -> Sprite
where you could never do
   SpriteBatchNode -> Node -> Sprite
because SpriteBatchNode could have only Sprites as children.